# How can I detect when I'm viewing vim's docs?

Tags: vim

I normally like setting `scrolloff=99`, but it's not ideal when I'm reading the help files. How can I detect when I'm in there so I can turn `scrolloff` off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim has a special `filetype` for help docs called `help`. So you may use an `autocmd` to set it conditionally in your `.vimrc`. This requires using `BufEnter` conditionally to match the `'help'` filetype.

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == 'help'| set scrolloff=0 | else | set scrolloff=99 | endif
```

Comment: `'scrolloff'` is a global setting. So you will need a more advanced `autocmd`. Probably a `WinEnter` event

Comment: @PeterRincker Indeed. `BufEnter` seems to work. This can probably be improved to one line still..

Comment: You may want to consider using an `:augroup` with a `:au!` as the first autocmd inside to make it resistant to re-sourcing. Yes it can be shorter. `autocmd BufEnter * let &scrolloff = &filetype == 'help' ? 0 : 99`